# Scroll in infinite scroll div with headless [Robot-Framework]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, robotframework

I'm have an test scenario where i need to scroll the screen down so the element can be loaded in the HTML. Using Headless as False the test goes as planned but as soon I run it with Headless as True, the scroll is executed but the HTML isen't loaded and my test fail.

My test scenario is like this:

```
Open_course
    [Tags]    Q-18
    Login Access
    Wait Until Element Is Visible            ${pageHome.ContinueStudying}
    Execute Javascript                       window.scrollBy(0,1000)
    Click                                    ${pageHome.courseHowtoTest}
    Click                                    ${pageHome.buttonIWant}
```

This is how the website stay when the scroll is executed in Headless == True:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHVO4.jpg

Obs: I blurried the image for anonymity.

After the two last cards, it should load more course cards.

I looked up if someone had the same problem but didn't find any correleted issues.

I don't know if it is some limitation from the robot framework working with infinite scroll in headless mode or there is some other javascript command that work better with infinite-scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Sleep      2s` after you scroll all the way down before clicking or use `Wait Until Element Is Visible       ${pageHome.courseHowtoTest}`

Comment: I didn't try using sleep. Will try and comeback here with the result.

Comment: Update: Tried using `Sleep      2s` but the got the same result.
About the keyword `Wait Until Element Is Visible` it is already inside the custom keyword `Click`

Comment: Try `Scroll Element Into View` keyword  instead of  `Execute Javascript   window.scrollBy(0,1000 )` . [Documentation](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Scroll%20Element%20Into%20View)

Comment: The problem with `Scroll Element Into View` is that the element must exist in the HTML. In my case, the element still doesn't exist. This is the reason why i need to scroll till the element appears

Answer (score 0):

The lazy loading of data might not be triggered by using headless mode in combination with scrolling by executing Javascript, though this is just a guess. Pressing the `PageDown` or `Space` key might work as an alternative.

```
Press Keys    none    PAGE_DOWN
```

Or when multiple pages need to be scrolled:

```
Press Keys    none    PAGE_DOWN    PAGE_DOWN    PAGE_DOWN
```

When the number of pages to scroll is unknown, using a loop is recommended.

Comment: I forgot about the `Press Keys` keyword but the result was the same. The rest of the page doesn't load in headless mode.

Comment: Ok, it was just a guess. Headless and non-headless mode shouldn't differ. Let us know when you found the solution. Good luck.